What animal does this skull belong to? I found it in a cave buried in the dirt, with other bones

I did not find anything similar on Google.

You should include where in the world this was found (city/country/etc) and its length

Herbivore - something with large chewing muscles given the sagittal crest.

a shot of the teeth will tell you a lot more than a top veiw of the skull. teeth and their placment in the jaw will tell you a lot in mammals. Scale is also important, how long is it. Just from what i can see I am guessing some kind of canine.

@bob1 lots of carnivores have large sagitical crests.
